# Generating Random Vectors Given a Euclidean Norm in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

To be specific, let's say I have a Euclidean norm = x. I want to generate a single random vector that also has its norm = x, with some random dimension that I will input. Is there a mathematical solution for this that I can apply in python to generate this vector?

I have seen similar posts regarding the one-norm, but I am looking specifically for the Euclidean norm so not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Let me know if I'm missing something here. You have a vector `a` such that `||a||2 = x` and you want to construct a random vector `b` such that `||b||2 = x`?

Comment: Yes you're right. I'm looking to construct the random vector b in python, with the same dimensions as the previous vector a.

Comment: Marked as duplicate.  The specific norm is irrelevant if you're looking for a random orientation.